# Why is $\sqrt{x^2}$ is $|x|$?

Tags: exponentiation

I was trying a problem and was getting the wrong answer and when I saw the solution on the internet I found this statement written in square brackets $\sqrt{x^2}$[note square is on $x$] is $|x|$. Till now I have learned that by laws of exponents we can multiply the powers and obtain $\sqrt{x}^2$ as $x$. But this seems confusing to me. Please clear this doubt.

And does this apply to $\left({\sqrt x}\right)^2$[note square is on radical] i.e. is $\left({\sqrt x}\right)^2 = |x|$?

Comment: What is $(-1)^2$ ? What is $\sqrt1$ ? Then what is $\sqrt{(-1)^2}$ ?

Comment: "Till now I have learnt that by laws of exponents" What _exactly_ do those laws say? Because I think you missed a small, but very important detail.

Comment: @Arthur can you tell what is that.

Comment: @ShreyanshKuntal: if you don't tell how you interpret the "laws of exponent", we cannot tell you why you are wrong.

Comment: If non-integer exponents are involved, the base must be non-negative , otherwise the law $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ does not hold in general. In fact, within the reals $a^b$ can be undefined. The reason that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is not just $x$ is that the convention of a square-root is that the non-negative possibility is meant, and for negative $x$, we get therefore $-x$. If we start with $\sqrt{x}$ , we must (at least in the reals) assume that $x\ge 0$ and then $(\sqrt{x})^2=x$ follows from the exponential law.

Comment: @Peter That's really an answer, not a comment. In fact, _my_ above comment is borderline, in my opinion.

Comment: @Arthur There are already $3$ answers. Usually, I do not add another answer in this case, since usually everything has been said. But I think, it is a useful summary.

Comment: @Peter then can we say [(x)^(1/n)]^n is not equal to x.

Comment: For $x\ge 0$ , it surely is equal $x$, but for negative $x$, we can have problems. However, if $n$ is an odd positive integer, it works, since the $n$ th root is negative and the equation therefore valid.. The reason is that $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is  bijective in this case, so also negative values work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square root of $x$ is a *non-negative* number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. Thus the square root of $x^2$ is a non-negative number $y$ such that $y^2=x^2$. To make sure the square root of $x^2$ is non-negative then you take $y=\lvert x\rvert$.

In the second part, writing $(\sqrt{x})^2$ means that $x \geq 0$, so $\lvert x\rvert = x$, and you can safely say $(\sqrt{x})^2 = x$.

Answer (score 2):

We know that, for any $x\in \Bbb R^+$ there exist two $y\in\Bbb R : y^2=x$, namely $y=y_+$ and $y=y_-=-y_+$.

Therefore, the inverse of the function $ f:\Bbb R\mapsto \Bbb R :f(x)=x^2$ will be one-to-many (i.e. $f^{-1}(4)=2$ and $f^{-1}(4)=-2$ simultaneously)

This breaks the definition of a function, which must be one-to-one or many-to-one.

So we define $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt x=|y|=y_+$ so that the function is one-to-one  and therefore valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer:**

$$\left(\sqrt x\right)^2=|x|$$ obviously holds because the expression is only defined for $x\ge0$. For the same reason,

$$\left(\sqrt x\right)^2=x$$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\sqrt{x^2}$ is (the unique) non-negative number $a$
such that $a^2 = x^2$. I guess you will agree with this.

Now... if we take $|x|$ we see that this number $|x|$ satisfies both
conditions for $a$ i.e. it is non-negative and its square is $x^2$. So $|x| = a$